# PCB Layers power and ground plane

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I have noticed that professionally done board always fill top and bottom with GROUND planes. As i have been making PCB board myself i find that having the top layer POWER fill and bottom layer a GROUND fill.On 2 Layer PCB what are differences between using POWER and GROUND fills as opposed to GROUND and GROUND fills?

Further more for Multi-Layer PCBs I have noticed that the stacked seems to be like SIGNAL GROUND POWER SIGNAL. why is that? wont filling the outer most layer with ground/power protect the signal traces more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The best stack-up possible with a four-layer PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41470/the-best-stack-up-possible-with-a-four-layer-pcb)

Comment: *I have noticed that professionally done board always fill top and bottom with GROUND planes* - that would be very unusual if not downright wrong in 99% of jobs. You are probably mistaken.

Comment: The biggest thing for a ground-plane is for it to be unbroken - you don't want a bunch of islands where return current has to travel a huge path-length to actually return. That's why internal layers are often desirable, they're just a solid, continuous flood of copper with no traces, just vias coming down through it.

Comment: @Justme partially though, how about the 2 layer pcb? what would be the difference PWR-GND to GND-GND

Comment: @Andyaka true, i cant even tell if the board is even professionally or not made. It more like an observation i made that GND-GND fill is what seems to be popular or what is see most of the time.

Comment: @Orotavia Oh it being just a solid is important, So when desinging a 2 layer PCB it would be verry good if one of those layer does not contain any signal traces.